# Wrong UITableViewCellEditingStyle once new row has been added in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a custom controller that manages a tableView and once entered in editing mode it adds a new row (used to insert new records). The problem is that the row below that one just added get displayed with the **UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert** too. I can fix the display by calling **reloadData** but I loose the cool animations provided by the framework :P
I tried also using a delay, but the result is pretty sucky :(

The following is my overridden method:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
    NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:path];

    if (editing) {
        GTMLoggerDebug(@"add row");
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    } else {
        GTMLoggerDebug(@"remove row");
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
}
```

ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit stale, but I had the same problem and this is how I solved it:
First - don't call `[self.tableView setEditing:animated:]` as this is already called when you call `[super setEditing:animated:]`

Next - Place your call to `-beginUpdates` before your call to `[super setEditing:animated:]`

Next: get rid of your reloadData.

This solved it for me, no more insert where it should be delete.